# cuda error while generating features from resnet50

Tags: python, pytorch

I am attempting to generate features using ResNet-50 and loading the model onto my GPU to speed up the process. Here is the code I am using:

```
import torch
from torchvision import transforms
from transformers import AutoImageProcessor, ResNetModel
from tqdm import tqdm

# Check if GPU is available, otherwise use CPU
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Load the image processor and ResNet-50 model
image_processor = AutoImageProcessor.from_pretrained("microsoft/resnet-50")
model = ResNetModel.from_pretrained("microsoft/resnet-50").to(device)

# Define the transformation to convert image to tensor
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor()
])

# Function to get features from an image using the model
def get_features_image(image):
    inputs = image_processor(image, return_tensors="pt")
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(**inputs)
    last_hidden_states = outputs.last_hidden_state
    return last_hidden_states

# List to store the computed features for training dataset
chart_features_train = []

# Iterate through the images in the training dataset
for image in tqdm(train_chart_dataset):
    image = image.convert("RGB")
    image_transformed = transform(image)
    
    # Move the transformed image tensor to the GPU
    image_cuda = image_transformed.to(device)
    
    # Compute features for the image and append to the list
    chart_features_train.append(get_features_image(image_cuda))
```

However, I encounter the following error during the execution:

```
RuntimeError: Input type (torch.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) should be the same
```

Answer (score 0):

this was the problem

```
inputs = image_processor(image, return_tensors="pt").to(device)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).